# Jquery match two classes with same number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this which matches 2 id's, is there a similar way in jQuery to do the same with classes...

```
$('#action_' + this.id.replace('switch_', ''));
```

tried...

```
$('action_' + this.replaceWith('switch_', ''));
```

but obviously didn't work otherwise I wouldn't be here :-)

Here is the piece of code I am working with...

```
$('input[id^="switch_"]').change(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('#actionSel_' + this.replaceWith('switch_', '')).prop('disabled',false).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
                $('.antenna').button('enable').trigger("change");
            } else {
                $('#actionSel_' + this.replaceWith('switch_', '')).prop({'disabled': true, 'selectedIndex': 0}).trigger("chosen:updated").trigger("change");
                $('.antenna').prop('checked', false).button('disable').trigger('change');
            }
        });
```

Basically rather than id's need to you classes, because of numerous forms on the page... I think... Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Si

Comment: You want to change the class ?

Comment: Did you miss out `.className` in your second snippet?

Comment: And maybe a `.` in your css selecter

Comment: what is `this` in your context?

Comment: Can you edit your question and be more specific ?..

Comment: Sorry guys should have explained more... I am trying to match the class of an action to the class of a switch, so checkbox 1 will trigger action 1 etc.

Comment: @Simon, can you provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduced your problem?

Comment: Be aware; _"I currently have this which matches 2 id's"_ — you shouldn't ***have*** two elements with the same `id`. That is illegal and applying css or selecting them with js may have unpredictable results.

Comment: @StephenP, I am not using two of the same id... what the current code does is match #actionSel_1, with #switch_1 etc...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
$('.action_' + this.id.replace('switch_', ''));
```

Use `.` to refer a control with css classes in jquery, like you used `#` with the id.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery (and CSS) selectors, use .item to match classes and #item to match ids:

```
$('.action_' + this.replaceWith('switch_', ''));
```

Comment: Sorry guys should have explained more...
I am trying to match the class of an action to the class of a switch, so checkbox 1 will trigger action 1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *match two classes with same number* and the format is always `classname_number` (e.g. `action_1`, `switch_2`, etc.), then this code will help you:

```
$('.' + class1 + '_' + class2.split('_')[1]);
```

For example,

```
$('.' + 'action' + '_' + 'switch_3'.split('_')[1]);
```

will return all elements that contain `action_3` class.